# Displaying saving/discount price in cart page

Tags: discount

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/amaze/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

In above file i have added the bellow snippet code to display saving amount for each product and its working good now in this loop i have to save addition of  `$finaltot`

suppose `$finaltot` displaying value 10 23 40 so i have to make like 10 + 23 + 40

I have tried with bellow code to make addition in  `$finaltot+` but its no working

```
<?php
    $product_orignalprice = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $discountedprice=$_item->getPrice(); 
    $todatlsaving=$product_orignalprice-$discountedprice;
    $finaltot+=$todatlsaving * $this->getQty();
    echo $finaltot;
?>
```

so it will display $finaltot=73

so how do I do this within loop to store all value of variable in one variable.

you can check code on [pastebin.com/YMGvEmr7](http://pastebin.com/YMGvEmr7) on the line 96 to 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have done this with own way if you want display saving price of every product in cart and display to total saving amount near at Grand Total you need edit two file of your theme.

1)Display saving amount front of each product.

Add bellow snippet code in `/app/design/frontend/rwd/your_theme_name/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

Check the cart div html markup where exactly you have to display `saving price`  because every theme have different lay out just put the bellow code in proper place.

```
<span class="savepricecustm">You Saved Rs
  <?php 
    $product_orignal_price = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $discounted_price=$_item->getPriceInclTax(); 
    $total_saving=$product_orignal_price-$discounted_price;
    $final_tot+=$total_saving * $this->getQty();
    echo $final_tot;
  ?>
</span>
```

2) Display total saving amount of all product in the cart near at `Grand Total`

Add bellow snippet code in

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/your_theme_name/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml
```

Add this code after `<?php echo $this->renderTotals();` in my case so you can put this according to your theme structure.

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $productPrice_orignal_price=$item->getProduct()->getPrice();
     $discountedprice=$item->getPrice(); 
     $todatlsaving=$productPrice_orignal_price-$discountedprice;
     $finaltot+=$todatlsaving * $item->getQty();
    }  
     $finaltot;
    ?>
    <p class="saveclss"><span class="savepricecustm">Total Saving</span>
    <span class="saving_session_price">Rs <?php
    echo money_format("%i",$finaltot);//echo $_SESSION["saving_session_price"]; ?>
    </span></p>
```

Out Put:-Now you will see effect of code in cart page like bellow.

[image: cart out put]

Note:- Updating the theme will overwrite this code.

Comment: For those who have tax included prices in cart page use this :-

$productPrice_orignal_price = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($item->getProduct(),$item->getProduct()->getPrice());

$discountedprice = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($item->getProduct(),$item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice());

Comment: But what if the product is configurable containing some child with a different price from the parent one?

Answer (score 2):

you can use like define `$finaltot`  out side loop = 0

```
$finaltot = $finaltot + ( $todatlsaving * $this->getQty());
```

so final code will look like

```
<?php
    $product_orignalprice = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $discountedprice=$_item->getPrice(); 
    $todatlsaving=$product_orignalprice-$discountedprice;
    $finaltot = $finaltot + ( $todatlsaving * $this->getQty());
    echo $finaltot;
?>
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: i tried this code but its showing different price like 60 and 30 i wanted some thing like 90

Comment: you can check code on http://pastebin.com/YMGvEmr7  on the line 96 to 100

Comment: how do i stop loop here